# Import from Excel to datagridview with OLEDB in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, oledb, oledbconnection

I'm using below code to import Excel sheet to datagridview. If there's no pre-defined columns in Datagridview there's no problem but i have pre-defined columns when i'm import the file it creates new columns. How is it possible to prevent this situation.

```
Public Shared Sub NewMethod2(ByVal dgv As DataGridView)
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim ofd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog With {
        .Filter = "Excel Files | *.xlsx",
        .Title = "Import Model Info Sheet"
    }
    Try
        If ofd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            filepath = Path.GetFullPath(ofd.FileName)
            Globals.ModelInfoSheet = filepath
        End If
        frmMain.Label1.Text = Globals.ModelInfoSheet
        dgv.DataSource = Nothing
        Dim MyConnection As OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim MyCommand As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        MyConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & Globals.ModelInfoSheet & "';Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
        MyCommand = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("srcTablePa", "setTablePa")
        Dim DtSet As DataTable
        DtSet = New DataTable
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
        dgv.DataSource = DtSet

        MyConnection.Close()

        MessageBox.Show("File successfully imported")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you needing to pre-define columns when this happens through the datasource property?

Comment: dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false

Comment: @JohnG i couldn't see this option on VS 2017.

Comment: You have to set this line in your code. You can put it in the `Form_Load` event or in the forms constructor AFTER `InitializeComponent();`. This property is not available in the “Designer”. Also note, that for each column that is already in the grid… you need to make sure that each column’s `DataPropertyName` MATCHES one of the column names in the `DataSource`.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this (between the Try...Catch)?

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
        Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
        Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\vb.net-informations.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
        MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
        MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Net-informations.com")
        DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
        MyConnection.Close()

    End Sub
End Class
```